# MySQL server will not start/stop

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql-workbench, command-line

I am currently in the process of setting up a database in MySQL for an application where I will be running PowerBI to do analyses on the data in the database and in a further stage to design an application to upload/download data from this db.

I tried to install the 8.0.23.0 Community Edition through the MySQL Installer. I installed MySQL Server, Shell, Workbench and the ODBC Connector (I want to use Access as a front end) and the NET Connector (I want to import the data in PowerBI). Furthermore I choose to not have MySQL running as a Windows Service as it would keep running in the background. I am currently using my machine with limited hardware resources both as a host and a client. We don't have dedicated infrastructure yet and I am purely using my machine to test/develop.

What I would like to be able to do is the following: starting the server instance through MySQL Workbench when working on the project, open Microsoft Access and PowerBI to work on both the reports and the database. After finishing, I would stop the server instance again through MySQL Workbench.

My problem is the following: I am not succeeding in stopping/starting the instance from Workbench and I get the following error message:[image]

I succeed in stopping the server instance through CMD but when trying to start again I get the following messages:[image]

Does anyone know wha I am doing wrong? Did I not install enough packages to get it running or did I configure someting wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The datadir directory does not exist. I tried to manually add one through file explorer and the error disappeared in CMD. However, after opening in Workbench I was still not able to connect as it seemed offline. Therefore, it seemed like the server did not start.

Furthermore, do you mean the MySQL account or my windows account? I did not any MySQL users as I am accessing with 'root'. My Windows Account is Administrator of this machine so I guess I have 'PERMIT ALL'?

Comment: *The datadir directory does not exist.* If so then server installation was performed wrongly. Remove it completely and reinstall.

Comment: Maybe also some good information to add: when I startup Workbench immediately after installing everything functions as should. It is solely after shutting down the database that the problems arise.

Comment: Tried to reinstall twice now, datadir does not show up for some reason...

Comment: look for an my.ini file, the service and all mysql start procidures should point to it usuqally it sis under `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working but not through workbench nor through CMD. I installed the server as a Windows service and wrote 2 batch files to start and stop the service.

Because of the difficulties and the limited resources on my own machine, I decided to go to an Azure SQL server, thank for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in Workbench. We have bug report for that start/stop issue. This problem was caused by migration from python2.7 to python3 and only affect last WB release. We working on that and it is already partially fixed.

Comment: Is there a way to have a workaround in te meantime? As I said, starting and stopping from CMD is also not working.